# What is the closed form for this sequence, powers of $4$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the closed form for this sequence:

1,  4,  12, 40, 148,    576,    2284,   9112,   36420,  145648, 582556, 2330184,    9320692,    37282720,   149130828,  596523256,  2386092964, 9544371792, 38177487100,    152709948328,
?

I know it has something to do with powers of $4$, possibly also powers of $2$. It turns up in an attempt to find an integral related to $\zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Comment: try https://oeis.org/, but it seems does not work...

Comment: All but the last 3 terms are odd terms of https://oeis.org/A068018 but that may just be coincidence.

Comment: This is probably stupid, but [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2C+4%2C+12%2C+40%2C+148%2C+576%2C+2284%2C+9112%2C+36420%2C+145648%2C+582556%2C+2330184%2C+9320692%2C+37282720%2C+149130828%2C+596523256%2C+2386092964%2C+9544371792%2C+38177487100%2C+152709948328) suggests a closed form being $$a_n = 1/36 (48 n+5 4^n-32) \text{ (for all terms given)}$$

Comment: The ratios between the numbers fluctuates a bit in the start but then converges to $4$, here's the ratios: 4, 3, 3.33333, 3.7, 3.89189, 3.96528, 3.98949, 3.99693, 3.99912, 3.99975, 3.99993, 3.99998, 3.99999, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4

Comment: The first differences are given by [A135583](https://oeis.org/A135583).

Comment: How did this sequence show up ?

Comment: @G.T.R The idea is to find the general formula for the row sums of variations of a recurrence in a lower triangular array giving the squares 1,4,9,16,25, as row sums, similar to the natural numbers here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/873899/successive-ratios-of-a-sequence-is-this-limit-true Then I want to integrate it and find a expression for partials sums of reciprocals of squares. But before that I need a formula, this sequence in the question is the row sums for recurrence sums multiplied by -2, when odd numbers are the first column in the lower triangular array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the first differences are given by [A135583](https://oeis.org/A135583) i.e. $$a(n+1)-a(n)=\frac{4+5\cdot 4^n}3$$
we may conjecture (with some tuning) that $$a(n)=1+\frac 13\left(4n+5\frac{4^{n}-1}{4-1}\right)$$
which appears right.