# Prove that the entries in this matrix essentially consists of the Dirichlet inverse of the Euler totient.

Tags: matrices, elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations

The [identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) satisfies the following recurrence:

```
(*Mathematica 8*)
Clear[t];
nn = 15;
t[1, 1] = 1;
t[n_, 1] = 0;
t[1, k_] = 0;
t[n_, k_] := 
  t[n, k] = 
   If[n < k, 
    If[And[n > 1, k > 1], 
     Sum[t[k - i, n - 1] - t[k - i, n], {i, 1, k - 1}], 0], 
    If[And[n > 1, k > 1], 
     Sum[t[n - i, k - 1] - t[n - i, k], {i, 1, n - 1}], 0]];
a = Table[Table[t[n, k], {k, 1, nn}], {n, 1, nn}];
MatrixForm[a]
```

Prove that the matrix: $$T(n,k)=a(GCD(n,k))$$
where GCD is the Greatest Common Divisor and the sequence a is the [Dirichlet Inverse of the Euler totient function](https://oeis.org/A023900), for $n>1$ and $k>1$, satisfies the following recurrence:

```
Clear[t];
nn = 15;
t[1, 1] = -1;
t[n_, 1] = 0;
t[1, k_] = 0;
t[n_, k_] := 
  t[n, k] = 
   If[n < k, 
    If[And[n > 1, k > 1], 
     Sum[t[k - i, n - 1] - t[k - i, n], {i, 1, n - 1}], 0], 
    If[And[n > 1, k > 1], 
     Sum[t[n - i, k - 1] - t[n - i, k], {i, 1, k - 1}], 0]];
a = Table[Table[t[n, k], {k, 1, nn}], {n, 1, nn}];
MatrixForm[a]
```

The only difference between the two programs is that the upper summation limits are different.

Comment: Related:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/873899/successive-ratios-of-a-sequence-is-this-limit-true